# Need to convert the given output in to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Output of the code giving  element with commas separated and I want the output 
in list

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([1,3,4,9,3,4,5,0,1])
lmax = (array[1:-1] > array[2:]) & (array[1:-1] > array[:-2])
j=np.arange(1, array.size-1)[lmax]
print(*j, sep=",")
```

Actual output= 3,6
Expected output =[3,6]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If  we remove the code (print(*j, sep=",")) I am getting the output with space before element 6.like[3, 6] but I want the output without space i.e[3,6]

Answer (score 0):

Just input your variable `j` into the `list` constructor.

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([1,3,4,9,3,4,5,0,1])
lmax = (array[1:-1] > array[2:]) & (array[1:-1] > array[:-2])
j=np.arange(1, array.size-1)[lmax]
lyst = list(j) # THIS LINE HERE IS NEW !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
print(lyst)
```

Comment: Here my output is coming with space before the index 1 i.e[3, 6] but I want the output without space i.e[3,6]

Comment: can some one help to resolve this issue.Thanks in advance